# React/Redux skipping a line during onClick event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I have the following Component that is in charge of a few things

1. Displaying a Move
2. Attaching an onClick Event to that move that will trigger a long dispatch
   2a. In this dispatch, an opponent move is selected from an existing Opponent Object's moves array.
3. The Event Listener Function will determine whose attack goes first, and then dispatch each one making the appropriate changes to the state.

The code below works about 80% of the time, in fact, it will ALWAYS work for at least three different instances (pick a move, handle the dispatches, pick another, dispatch again, etc.), but then after three, (often more) a line just gets skipped.

Upon a click, the `processMoves` function is called which will handle steps 2a and 3. Again, this almost always works, but sometimes the line `let oppMoveObj = makeOppMoveSelection(opp)` gets skipped, breaking everything beneath it. I know it skips this line because inside that very function, I have a `debugger` and multiple `console.log` statements that WILL get hit the first three or more clicks. The code is below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import makeOppMoveSelection from '../../helpers/oppMoveSelection';
import { moveAction } from '../../helpers/moveHelper';
import './Move.css'

// PROPS MEHTODS
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return(
        {battle: state.battle}
    )
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return({
            chooseMove: (move, props) => processMoves(move, props),
            executeMove: (move, attacker) => dispatch(moveAction(move, attacker)),
            initiateMoveProcess: () => dispatch({type: 'MOVE_SELECTED'}),
            completeMoveprocess: () => dispatch({type: 'MOVE_PROCESS_COMPLETE'})
        })
}
// PROPS METHODS



// This will handle everything battle related after move selection. This includes...
    // 1. Accepts the selected move from the User
    // 2. Selects a move from the Opponent's available moves
    // 3. Determines if they are shocked, they move last
    // 4. Determines if any move has 'move first' effect, if so that move goes first
    // 5. Compares speed to determine which move goes first
    // 6. If any figure has 0 health after any move, the battle ends
    // 7. After the moves are executed, applies any damage from status effects
function processMoves(moveObj, props){
    // Assigns global values
    let opp = props.battle.opp
    let user = props.battle.user

    // Selects a move that the opponent uses
    let oppMoveObj = makeOppMoveSelection(opp)

    // Removes the move selection screen for the message 
    props.initiateMoveProcess()  // ERROR OCCURS HERE

    // If someone is using a move that moves first
    if (moveObj.effect == "move first" && oppMoveObj.effect != "move first"){
        props.executeMove(moveObj, "user")
        props.executeMove(oppMoveObj, "opp")
    }
    else if (oppMoveObj.effect == "move first" && moveObj.effect != "move first"){
        props.executeMove(oppMoveObj, "opp")
        props.executeMove(moveObj, "user")
    }

    // If someone is shocked the other goes first
    else if (opp.status == "shocked" && user.status != "shocked"){
        props.executeMove(moveObj, "user")
        props.executeMove(oppMoveObj, "opp")
    }
    else if (opp.status != "shocked" && user.status == "shocked"){
        props.executeMove(oppMoveObj, "opp")
        props.executeMove(moveObj, "user")
    }

    // Handles everything else
    else{
        if (user.spd >= opp.spd){
            props.executeMove(moveObj, "user")
            props.executeMove(oppMoveObj, "opp")
        }
        else{
            props.executeMove(oppMoveObj, "opp")
            props.executeMove(moveObj, "user")
        }
    }
}

class Move extends Component{


    handleClick = (event, props) => {
        let indexofMove = parseInt((event.target.offsetParent.id.split("e")[1]), 10)
        let selMove = this.props.battle.user.moves[indexofMove]
        this.props.chooseMove(selMove, props)
    }

    render(){
        return(
            // get the index in as a prop from move container.
            // This way, we can access the battle.user.moves and find the move that way for the dispatch. 
            // Meaning, the event would track the id of the div it clicked, and then use that id as the index 
            // of the move in the user.moves array to send in the dispatch and figure out all the damage
            <div className={`MoveCard ${this.alterClassNameBasedOnCoolDown(this.props)}`} id={`MoveCard${this.props.index}`}
                onClick = {(event) => this.handleClick(event, this.props)}>
                <p id="name">{this.props.m.name}</p>
                <p id="type">Type: {this.props.m.type}</p>
                <p id="acc">Accuracy: {this.props.m.acc}</p>
                <p id="dmg">{this.pow_or_heal(this.props.m.dmg)} {this.props.m.dmg}</p>
                <p id="cool">Cooldown: {this.props.m.cool}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Move)
```

## QUICK EDIT

My oppMoveSelection.js file looks like this...

```
export default function makeOppMoveSelection(opp){
    let cooled = opp.moves.map( (move) => {
        if (move.tillCooldown == 0){
            return move
        }
    })
    if (opp.hp < 50 ){
        cooled.forEach(element => {
            if (element.dmg < 0){
                return element
            }
        });
    }
    else{
        let len = cooled.length
        let indexSel = Math.floor(Math.random() * len)
        console.log("Inside opp move picker")
        console.log(cooled)
        console.log("Index selected: " + indexSel)
        return opp.moves[indexSel]
    }

}
```

I really have no idea what could be making the compiler skip a line entirely, and since oppMoveObj is never defined, I'll then get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'effect' of undefined` even though it would have worked perfectly numerous times before. Does anybody see what could be wrong?

Comment: JavaScript cannot skip lines and using Redux does not magically make it. I assume there is a condition where your `makeOppMoveSelection` can just return `undefined`. Can you share the implementation of `makeOppMoveSelection`?

Comment: I just added it to the question under the # Quick Edit header... What makes me CONFIDENT the method is getting skipped is the console.log() statements don't even get hit, whereas they will the first times

Answer (score 0):

Those console.logs won't get hit if HP is below 50, so let's assume it goes in here.

Generally, I would suggest you write `debugger;` in the first line of your `makeOppMoveSelection` function and just observe what happens in the browser's devtools, but here is my guess:

Code enters your `.forEach`

```js
        cooled.forEach(element => {
            if (element.dmg < 0){
                return element
            }
        });
```

and at some point it will do `return element`. But you assume that would want to `return` from `makeOppMoveSelection`. In reality though, it will only `return` from the arrow function within your `.forEach`. And then that loop just continues running the next iteration, finishes, and `makeOppMoveSelection` finishes without ever having hit a `return` statement.

This is a problem with using `.forEach` and honestly, I would just never use that function, ever again. It is just a legacy artefact since ES6 introduced `for or` loops back in 2015.

So use one of those instead:

```js
        for (const element of cooled) {
            if (element.dmg < 0){
                return element
            }
        });
```

that will behave as you expect.